# Interpreting eigenvectors for an oscillatory Markov process

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Consider a 3-state system with states A, B, C such that at each discrete time step, the system advances with 100% certainty to the next state, e.g.

A - B - C - A - B...

The transition matrix for this system is

```
[0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 0]
```

My intuition for this system says there are two modes:
1. A stationary mode with equal probability mass in each state
2. A periodic mode where the distribution repeats every 3 steps

Mode 1 should correspond to an eigenvalue of 1, which is guaranteed to exist for a Markov transition matrix. The eigenvector should be $[1/3, 1/3, 1/3]^T$

Mode 2 should correspond to a complex eigenvalue. The real and complex parts of the eigenvector should span the plane which intersects [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], and [0, 0, 1].

However, complex eigenvalues always come in conjugate pairs for real matrices! This would seem to imply a periodic mode which is rotating in the opposite direction, and that doesn't make sense to me for this system. How should I interpret this 3rd eigenvalue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will see much more clearly what is happening if you find the two complex eigenvectors and let your matrix act upon each of them.

You will notice that both are 'rotating' in the same direction. When a real vector is a linear sum of these two vectors it then also rotates in this direction as you would expect.

Comment: It's interesting, the eigenvectors also turn out to be a conjugate pair, which seems like there actually is no additional "information" - the dynamics are the same as the other eigenpair. Is there some other interpretation of this 3rd vector, outside of a dynamics context?

Comment: When we consider the matrix acting on vectors with complex terms, we are in effect treating it as a transformation of 6-D space. The eigenvalues/eigenvectors tell us that, for a suitable choice of axes,  the matrix is fixing two dimensions and rotating the other axes in pairs. The original 3-D matrix is what we get if we only look at what is happening in three particular (real) directions. This interpretation is very useful when thinking about electrical engineering problems where one is looking at a 1-D restriction of a relatively simple rotation but is hard to visualise for Markov processes.